# what's in a node.js elastic beanstalk zip file and how do I get it to run a script on deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Should the zip file of my application include the node_modules folder?  Should I be zipping up a top-level folder that contains all my application files or should I not include the top root folder like the instructions for amazon lambda?

Do I have to set the web application port to an environment variable like in heroku?  Does the app start by calling npm start and looking at the package.json or do I have to have a file called server.js like in opsworks?

How can I have it run a small migration script before it starts - can I just put that in npm start?

Can I get it to run npm install on deployment rather than copying over the node_modules folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick answers:

1. No, the zip file does not need to include the node_modules folder.  EB will run `npm install` for you.
2. There are several ways to run a script at start.  `npm start` would be one, you can also run [custom commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).
3. Yes, EB will run `npm start`, see [Configuration Options for node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-nodejs)

The best answer would be to take a look at one of Amazon's sample apps, such as [nodejs-example-express](http://elasticbeanstalk-samples-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/nodejs-example-express.zip) from [Deploying an Express Application to Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html).